# How can I draw a curved path with a gradient on the html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gradient

With javascript I am drawing a 'curved' path on the canvas element which consists of many small straight segments here: [Harmonograph](http://www.ashware.nl/harmonograph).

Now I want each segment to have a different color, to have the rainbow colors apply along the path.
So the path starts with red, then gradually changes to yellow, then to green, etc..

I want to use the `beginPath()` and `closePath()` only once to speed things up.
Is this possible with a function like `createLinearGradient();` or any other standard function, as long as it's fast because the whole path needs to be redrawn many times per second.

Comment: Please post the code you are using currently.

Comment: @Asad, pasting code doesn't seem to work...
But I think you already found the code I'm using [here](http://www.ashware.nl/harmonograph/js/harmonograph0.5.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing this other than separating the paths. Here is my implementation of a rainbow gradient for your lissajous figure. You can see a demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRMGy/show/):

```
drawLissajous: function(points) {
    if (points.length > 2) {
        var x, y, x = points[1][0] + this.centerX;
        y = points[1][1] + this.centerY;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        for (var count = 2; count < points.length; count++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            var newX = points[count][0] + this.centerX,
                newY = points[count][1] + this.centerY,
                f = 0.005,
                blue = Math.sin(f * count + 0) * 127 + 128,
                red = Math.sin(f * count + 2) * 127 + 128,
                green = Math.sin(f * count + 4) * 127 + 128;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.round(red) + ', ' + Math.round(green) + ', ' + Math.round(blue) + ')';
            x = newX;
            y = newY;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I am looking for. It surprises me that the speed is still high. Nice way to go through the rainbow colors too!

Comment: @Esger No problem. You could also experiment with the sine functions being used: for example, you could tweak the pattern by giving each wave a separate frequency. Or you could make the  pattern less red by decreasing the constant being added at the end.

Answer (score -2):

i have same question and i done a simple test and it is work
just use normal gradient , hope it be useful

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 20);

    // line 1
    context.lineTo(200, 160);

    // quadratic curve
    context.quadraticCurveTo(230, 200, 250, 120);

    // bezier curve
    context.bezierCurveTo(290, -40, 300, 200, 400, 150);

    // line 2
    context.lineTo(500, 90);

    // create radial gradient
    var grd = context.createRadialGradient(238, 50, 10, 238, 50, 300);
    // light blue
    grd.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');
    // dark blue
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');

    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = grd;
    context.stroke();
```

[here test](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsadeghy/LH9Zc/)

Comment: This is wrong. You're creating a radial gradient superimposed on the line, as opposed to a gradient that follows the line.